# Django - ajax call for loading page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I need really help..

I'm not good at front-end and I'm very confused with Ajax.

I'm trying to do an Ajax call for when I click on a button of my table so when I hit that button my ajax should show my animation .gif so the user should know that the page is loading.

my template:

```
<style>
    .ajaxProgress{
        display:none;
        text-align: center;

    }
</style>
<div id="output">
    <div class="ajaxProgress">
    <h3>Please wait..</h3>
    <img src="{% static 'img/ajax.gif' %}" alt="loading"/>
    </div>
</div>
            {% for item in qs  %}
            <tr> 
            <tbody>
                <td 
                a id="mqtt" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"   title="mqtt" href="javascript: startAjax(){% url 'start_mqtt' item.id %}"><span class="fa fa-signal"></span> </a> </td>
                </tbody>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>


        <script>

function startAjax() {
    $('.ajaxProgress').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType:"json",
        async: true,
        data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
        success: function(json){
            $('#output').html(json.message);
            $('.ajaxProgress').hide();
            GetRating(json.message);
        }
    })

}
</script>
```

Basically what I need is when I hit on the button should start my .gif but nothing happens....

Answer (score 0):

```
var $loading = $('.ajaxProgress').hide();
$(document)
.ajaxStart(function () {
    $loading.show();
 })
.ajaxStop(function () {
     $loading.hide();
});
```

I like to use this way

Comment: first check where the loading image is located calling show() function. This might be showing but you can't see. make sure it is in the middle of the page by changing the css. if it is clear the above will work for any ajax call if you call the ajax successfully.